# How to geotag photos from KML files

Tags: kml, photos, geotag

I am using an application called Gaia GPS to analyze regions affected by large enterprises. So, when I travel to this specific places I mark waypoints and take pictures before, during and at the end of the operations. With this I can analyse lots of factors that could affect the socioenvironmental areas.

Gaia Gps gives me a KMZ file with everything inside, waypoints, routes, photos. At this point ok. I could open this files perfectly on Google Erath Pro. When I export this KMZ using Google Earth it gives me all photos with a KML file. The problem is that the pictures doesn't have EXIF geotag info, neither time where the photos where taken. At the end all I have is a bunch of photos without individual georeferenced information.

```
<Placemark>
            <name>Minha Foto - 12/02/2021 09:57:23</name>
            <description>
<![CDATA[Location: -24,93659, -51,38044<br>
Elevation: 838,0 m<br>
Time Created: 12/02/2021 09:57:23 BRT<br>
<img src="4c70a6f5472e79f402eb2cd6c8f88e4e.jpg"><br><img src="751f1f165c3a19807d339ef4a499bdd6.jpg"><br>]]>
            </description>
    <styleUrl>#sh_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
    <Point>
        <coordinates>-51.38044207361656,-24.93658958005247,838</coordinates>
    </Point>
</Placemark>
```

If you pay attention, the excerpt of KML above show that all the information I need is put inside a custom field CDATA, All I need is to record this on the pictures.

Do you know a way to automatically do this (I have lots of pictures)?

I'm trying to solve this without success for a time now.

Comment: The gold standard for manipulating EXIF tags on photos semi-automatically is exiftool.org
If necessary, you should be able to convert the KML to a CSV using GDAL's `ogr2ogr`, then use exiftool to write the longitude and latitude into EXIF on the photos. However, I do find it surprising the GPS data is not in the photo - most cameras/devices record it automatically. So I'd check all the tags using exiftool to make sure it's not encoded in there somewhere already first.

Comment: For the timestamp, if not already somewhere in EXIF, you could extract the `name` or `description` attribute as a column in the CSV and then use a regexp expression to excise the timestamp from it. If this is all too obscure, ping me in the workweek and I'll write up in more detail -- but poke around the EXIF first since all of that should really be there!